# New GCM Implementation Running On Emulater having Issues

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, emulation, google-cloud-messaging

[image]

I am trying to Implement GCM for my application but emulator gives above message.

1. I have updated my Google API
2. I also include Google play service library project
3. I also add Google play service library
4. I also recreate my Emulator

Still my project wont run
this is my emulator details
[image]

when i try GCM with old GCMRegistrar library which is currently deprecated, is working with Emulator but when i Used new GCM google play services for GCM it shows above error message

Comment: try deleting existing emulator and create new one with same configuration.

Comment: @user3301551  i tried it but still giving same message

Comment: then open Application manager in Emulator and updated the `Google Play` application. This should work.

Comment: @user3301551 still not works :(

Comment: then better you should execute it in real device.

Comment: what is the version of your emulator ?

Comment: I don't know where should i get information about version of Emulator

Comment: Click on `Android Virtual Device Manager` from your tool bar then it will load all the emulator list.

Comment: @user3301551 check again I added Emulator Details

Comment: you are using API level 18 which is perfect. I thought you are using lower API, that's why I asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Include gcm.jar andgcm-src.jar file from your sdk location\sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist to your project library. Also dont forget create an emulator with GOOGLE API and add your google account in your emulator(emulator created with google api) settings-> account & sync settings -> add account -> google account -> now enter a valid google id and password.
Also you must have internet connection in your system, because these message is comming from google cloud message